# Eigen library. Calculate Inverse of a matrix, step by step. Matrix of cofactors

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

The easy way to calculate the inverse of a matrix is: mat.inverse()

But I want to calculate step by step as I did in High School, lot of years ago. I used to do:

```
inv A = 1/det(A) * transpose(Adj A)
```

I know how to calcultate determinant and transpose, but not the cofactor matrix.

I'm a little bit confused with the English terminology. I read googling:

'
In linear algebra, the adjugate, classical adjoint, or adjunct of a square matrix is the transpose of its cofactor matrix. (...) The adjugate has sometimes been called the "adjoint", but today the "adjoint" of a matrix normally refers to its corresponding adjoint operator, which is its conjugate transpose.
'

I just need the way to calculate the cofactor values for a 3x3 matrix, but it will be great if this method works for greater dimensions.

Comment: It may not be the easiest. It's one way, but it can be very costly to do it this way. What's the link with Eigen? I don't see any mention to Eigen in your question.

Comment: For sizes up to 4x4 (if known at compile time) Eigen uses an explicit cofactor method to calculate the inverse. Above that, doing an LU decomposition is usually more efficient. Check `Eigen/src/LU/InverseImpl.h` of your Eigen installation.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to calculate matrix determinant and adjugate matrix just to obtain inverse matrix. Laplace expansion is O(n!). Determinant calculation can be O(n3) (the same as matrix inversion itself ... ).

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense. It was just for didactical purposes, to follow the same procedure as the teacher do in the blackboard.